# Exercise 9, Section 5.B of Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T\in L(V)$, and $v\in V$ with $v\neq 0$. Let $p$ be a nonzero polynomial of smallest degree such that $p(T)v=0$. Prove that every zero of $p$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

**Approach (1):** Suppose $c$ is root of $p$. Then $\exists q\in F[x]$ such that $p=(x-c)q$. So $\deg (p)=\deg (x-c)+\deg (q)=1+\deg (q)$, and $\deg (q)\lt \deg(p)$. Since $p$ is smallest degree such that $p(T)v=0$, we have $q(T)(v)\neq 0$. Let $\alpha= q(T)(v)$. Then $p(T)(v)=(T-cI)q(T)(v)=(T-cI)(\alpha)=0$. So $T(\alpha)=c\alpha$. Hence $c$ is eigenvalue of $T$.

**Approach (2):** Let $S=\{f\in F[x]\mid f(T)(v)=0\}$. Then $S$ is non zero polynomial ideal. Let $g$ be monic generator of $S$. By uniqueness of monic generator, $p=dg$, for some $d\in F\setminus \{0\}$. Since minimal polynomial of $T$ is in $S$, we have $g|m_T$. If $p(c)=0$, then $g(c)=0$. So $m_T(c)=0$. Since minimal and characteristic polynomial of $T$ have same roots, we have $c$ root of characteristic polynomial of $T$. Thus $c$ is eigenvalue of $T$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I guess that in approach $(2)$, $m$ is the characteristic polynomial ? If so, both approaches seem correct.

Comment: @Zag $m$ denotes minimal polynomial of $T$. I changed it to $m_T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches look correct, as confirmed by Zag in the comments.